# coffeescript and haml in pop ups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml

```
popitup = (url) ->
  newwindow = window.open(url, "name", "height=200,width=150")
  newwindow.focus()  if window.focus
  false
```

this is my code but i want to link popup to a haml file instead of URL to appear in my pop up window

```
%h1 popup
br
%input{:name => "option1", :type => "checkbox", :value => "Milk"}
Milk                   
%br                   
%input{:name => "option2", :type => "checkbox", :value => "Butter"}                 
Butter                  
%br                   
%input{:name => "option3", :type => "checkbox", :value => "Cheese"}                    
Cheese                      
%br
```

this is the haml file
i'm using coffeescript

Answer (score 0):

You should create an action that displays the popup and use its url.

On an unrelated note, you should use labels for the text next to your checkbox, so that an user clicking on the text can toggle the checkbox.